# FTPS Upload works with cURL command but not with Apache Commons FTPClient

Tags: java, apache-commons, ftps, apache-commons-fileupload

The following command works to upload a file to our FTPS service provider:

```
curl --ftp-ssl -T test.txt ftp://username:password@ftp.hidrive.ionos.com/public/test.txt
```

I would like to achieve the same upload with Java using Apache Commons FTPSClient.
I created this small sample program

```
package com.sample.simulator;

import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;

import java.io.*;

public class Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String server = "ftp.hidrive.ionos.com";
        String user = "username";
        String pass = "password";

        FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(true);

        ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server);

            var success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            if(success) {
                System.out.println("Login successful");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Login failed");
            }

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            File firstLocalFile = new File("C:/Temp/test.txt");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

            String firstRemoteFile = "test.txt";

            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("public");
            var currentWorkingDir = ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory();
            System.out.println("Current working directory " + currentWorkingDir);

            System.out.println("Start uploading first file");

            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);

            inputStream.close();
            if (done) {
                System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
            } else {
                var reply = ftpClient.getReplyString();
                System.out.println("Upload failed " + reply );
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it always throws the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:647)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:525)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:112)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:449)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:316)
    at com.sample.simulator.Application.main(Application.java:21)
```

Setting the isImplicit - Flag in the Constructor of FTPSClient to false goes further but fails at the upload stage (because probably a different port would be used for data connection which is not setup at our provider).

```
220 Another visitor. Stay a while...
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH SSL OK.
USER username
331 FTP login okay, send password.
PASS password
230 User logged in, proceed.
Login successful
TYPE I
200 Using BINARY mode to transfer data.
CWD public
250 Directory changed to /public
PWD
257 "/public" is current directory.
Current working directory /public
Start uploading first file
PORT 192,168,0,4,243,243
550 Permission denied.
Upload failed 550 Permission denied.

QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Update:
When activating the flag -Djavax.net.debug=ssl i get the following output

```
C:\Users\xxx\.jdks\corretto-11.0.18\bin\java.exe -Djavax.net.debug=ssl "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=59373:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file1613146868 com.sample.simulator.Application -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 06:37:30.918 CEST|SSLCipher.java:464|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-06-01 06:37:31.262 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1654|handling exception (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:647)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:525)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:112)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:449)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:316)
    at com.sample.simulator.Application.main(Application.java:21)}

)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2023-06-01 06:37:31.263 CEST|TransportContext.java:345|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Connection reset by peer: socket write error (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:647)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:525)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:112)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:449)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:316)
    at com.sample.simulator.Application.main(Application.java:21)}

)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-06-01 06:37:31.264 CEST|TransportContext.java:392|Fatal: failed to send fatal alert UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:389)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1682)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:466)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:316)
    at com.sample.simulator.Application.main(Application.java:21)}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 06:37:31.264 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1737|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 06:37:31.264 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1756|close the SSL connection (initiative)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:647)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:525)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:112)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:449)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:316)
    at com.sample.simulator.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Update 2:
This is the verbose log output of the above curl command:

```
curl -v --ftp-ssl -T test.txt ftp://username:password@ftp.hidrive.ionos.com/public/testx2.txt

Warning: --ssl is an insecure option, consider --ssl-reqd instead
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 85.214.3.104:21...
* Connected to ftp.hidrive.ionos.com (85.214.3.104) port 21 (#0)
< 220 Another visitor. Stay a while...
> AUTH SSL
< 234 AUTH SSL OK.
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
> USER username
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< 331 FTP login okay, send password.
> PASS password
< 230 User logged in, proceed.
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ=0
> PROT P
< 200 Switched to protected data transfer mode.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD public
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 Directory changed to /public
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
* Failed EPSV attempt. Disabling EPSV
> PASV
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (85,214,3,104,230,253).
* Skip 85.214.3.104 for data connection, re-use ftp.hidrive.ionos.com instead
* Connecting to 85.214.3.104 (85.214.3.104) port 59133
*   Trying 85.214.3.104:59133...
* Connected to ftp.hidrive.ionos.com (85.214.3.104) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE I
< 200 Using BINARY mode to transfer data.
> STOR testx2.txt
< 150 Opening BINARY mode SSL data connection.
} [8 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Remembering we are in dir "public/"
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with ftp.hidrive.ionos.com port 21
< 226 Transfer complete. Closing data connection.
100     8    0     0  100     8      0     10 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    10
* Connection #0 to host ftp.hidrive.ionos.com left intact
```

Update 3:

When i use passive mode (new FTPSClient(false)) and entering localPassiveMode connect and login works but i get a permission error when uploading the file. How can this be when i am using the same credentials and the same folder as with cURL?

```
220 Another visitor. Stay a while...
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH SSL OK.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 12:54:27.190 CEST|SSLCipher.java:464|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 12:54:27.674 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1866|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 12:54:27.678 CEST|SSLCipher.java:2020|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 12:54:27.729 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1866|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 12:54:27.731 CEST|SSLCipher.java:2020|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
USER username
331 FTP login okay, send password.
PASS password
230 User logged in, proceed.
Login successful
TYPE I
200 Using BINARY mode to transfer data.
CWD public
250 Directory changed to /public
PWD
257 "/public" is current directory.
Current working directory /public
Start uploading first file
PASV
550 Permission denied.
Upload failed 550 Permission denied.

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 12:54:28.006 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:578|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-06-01 12:54:28.008 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1756|close the SSL connection (passive)
```

Is there any option i am missing which would correctly upload the file as the cURL command does?

Comment: *at com.sample.simulator.Application.main(Application.java:103)* What *is* line 103? Note that it's calling logout on a client. You posted the *full* stack trace?

Comment: @g00se the second exception is a result of the first one. i shorted the sample program a bit. line 103 is the call to ftpClient.logout(); 
the original (first) exception is thrown on the line ftpClient.connect(server);

Comment: Please post the *full stack trace* with code to match

Comment: @g00se I updated the sample source code and added the matching stacktrace.

Comment: And you can, immediately after such an error, successfully execute the curl command?

Comment: @g00se yes. they are 2 different applications connecting via different methods to the same service and the same user account.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure from that if authorization is finished. Perhaps not, in which case, running with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` might reveal something

Comment: I think that the default connection mode is active, which means that a different connection + port is used for file transfers. Can you try calling `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()`? I don't know if it's needed before or after the call to `connect`, you'd have to try that.

Comment: @g00se I added the output with activated debug flag to the original question.

Comment: @RobSpoor I think so too but i am not sure if it's possible with this library to reuse the same port for control and data connection. I tried your suggestion but it doesn't make a difference. I also tried enterLocalActiveMode() but still no change. I have to make the call before connect() because the exception is thrown at connect(). I also tried enterRemotePassiveMode() but for that i ned an open connection.

Comment: For local-passive, a _PASV_ command is typically sent before a data transfer.  This will create a separate socket connection, other than the control connection.  You'll want to call _enterLocalPassiveMode_ after the _login_ call.  Then any subsequent call to _storeFile_ should make a new _PASV_ connection first, before the transfer.

Comment: Did you turn on ssl debugging? There could be ssl manoeuvres involved with the *transfer* that are failing

Comment: Also worthwhile putting Curl into trace mode to see what it's doing, e.g. whether using PASV or EPSV. Maybe do that *before* my previous suggestion

Comment: @g00se Yes, i added SSL debug output of the sample program to the original question. Also i added the curl verbose output.

Comment: *Failed EPSV attempt. Disabling EPSV* could be of interest. You might find EPSV is enabled *by default* for IP4 connections. Try turning it off

Comment: @g00se: _curl_ tried EPSV for IP4, but for commons-net it is already disabled: https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-net/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java#588 . OP: in summary you need to set explicit SSL/TLS AND enterLocalPassiveMode.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for your comment. I updated the OP with the log output when using explicit mode and localPassiveMode. I do not understand why i get a permission error this way when the same thing works with cURL.

Comment: Looking at the logs the obvious difference is your system is not sending PROT, and if the server demands SSL/TLS for control it makes sense it would demand it for data also. I would have thought this would be done automatically but apparently not. From the source it looks like you can just call `.execPROT("P")` -- try that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you very much for that hint! It was not the full story though because i had to add a execPBSZ(0); before the call to execPROT("P"); (and enterLocalPassiveMode()). Please add an answer and i will accept.

Comment: Very nice detective work. Perhaps this weakness should be brought to the attention of the Apache devs? Of course, it would be much better to be using SSH rather than this patched-up old protocol. If that's possible, I'd strongly advise it

Comment: @g00se Thank you too for your support! In our project unfortunately we are bound to FTPS because of constraints of a protocol that is implemented on the devices uploading the files. Otherwise 100% agree.